# Google App Engine Channel API MESSAGE QUEUES

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

If a client is connected and then disconnects - say his connection is lost for 5 mins;  does the server queue the messages that can't be delivered?

On the local development server this seems to be the case?

If this is the case in production - how long are the messages queued for?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In production the messages are dropped if your server receives the /_ah/channel/disconnected/ POST.

In practice there's a tiny bit of caching. If you eg. lose your connection very briefly because your wifi connection drops, a message sent during that time could be queued up and delivered. But you shouldn't get the disconnect POST in that case.

Comment: The disconnect message arrives where on the client or on the server, thanks.

Comment: I'm talking about the POST to /_ah/channel/disconnected/ that happens if you enable channel_presence in inbound_services.